# How to authorize facebook app with javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created this simple code:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        alert('connected');// connected

      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

      alert('not_authorized');// not_authorized


      } else {
        alert('not_logged_in');// not_logged_in
        login();
      }
```

And here is the login function, but if I use the login() in the not_autorhized section, the window appear and immediately close (automaticaly)

```
function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // connected            
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    });
}
```

But how to authorize the app in javascript?

here is my full code: http://pastebin.com/Qv9ayb9V

Comment: if you go to the Facebook Developer page, you will find the answer you need.

Comment: did you define a `login` function that wraps `FB.login`?

Comment: You’re getting a response from FB.login – why haven’t you checked what it contains by logging it to the console?

Comment: I try, and the it jump to the else (cancelled). But I dont know why...

Answer (score 2):

Updated based on your updated information, now it is a shot in the dark...

You have probably already authenticated your app? and are logged in to facebook.

Try going to facebook.com and logging out. (or using FB.logout()) THen log back in to your site.  You should be required to login in the popup

---

Facebook provides step by step guide on their site explaining how to do this.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

Did you define the `login` function? It is not provided by facebook:

```
function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // connected
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    });
}
```

FB.login takes an additional param with some config options: one is the `scope`

`{scope: 'email,publish_actions'}`

```
   function login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // connected
            } else {
                // cancelled
            }
        }, {scope: 'email,publish_actions'});
    }
```

Comment: The problem is now, the popup window appear and immediately close.

Comment: @CarlMark Did you try logging out of facebook?

Comment: I created a new version of my code here: http://pastebin.com/index/Qv9ayb9V please see it. thanks a lot.